# Docker command for multiple tensorflow serving model?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to execute this normal tf_serving command (which work correctly) with docker version of tf_serving. I'm not sure why it's not working.. Any suggestion? I'm new to Docker!

**Normal tf_serving command:**

```
tensorflow_model_server \
--model_config_file=/opt/tf_serving/model_config.conf \
--port=6006
```

**here is what my model_config.conf looks like:**

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name: "model_1",
    base_path: "/opt/tf_serving/model_1",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
  },
  config: {
    name: "model_2",
    base_path: "/opt/tf_serving/model_2",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
  },
}
```

**Docker version of command that I'm trying but not working:**

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia \
-p 6006:6006 \
--mount type=bind,source=/opt/tf_serving/model_1,target=/models/model_1/ \
--mount type=bind,source=/opt/tf_serving/model_2,target=/models/model_2/ \
--mount type=bind,source=/opt/tf_serving/model_config.conf,target=/config/model_config.conf \
-t tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu --model_config_file=/config/model_config.conf
```

**Error:**

> 2019-04-13 19:41:00.838340: E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:369] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a file-system access error: Could not find base path /opt/tf_serving/model_1 for servable model_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue! You have to change the models path in model_config.conf as follow, and the above docker command will work and load both models!

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name: "model_1",
    base_path: "/models/model_1",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
  },
  config: {
    name: "model_2",
    base_path: "/models/model_2",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
  },
}
```

**EDIT**: corrected typo on `base_path` for `model_2`.

Comment: You can simplify the docker command above to this: `docker run --runtime=nvidia \
-p 6006:6006 
--mount type=bind,source=/opt/tf_serving/,target=/models/
-t tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu --model_config_file=/models/model_config.conf`. This will allow you to add more models without having to change the cmd. The reason for your initial error is that inside tf serve server, it only seems the target mount point of `/models/`, and not the host machine's `/opt/`.

Comment: Hi, I guess the 2nd `config.base_path` in `model_config_list` should be "models/model_2"